Understanding setCeption
Let's have the sets:
$$
A=\{R,G,B\} \\
B=\{A,C,T,G\} \\
$$
How would the union of those two look like? Is it like:
$$A\cup B=\{R,G,B,A,C,T\}$$ or since they are already contained in one another:
$$A\cup B=\{R,G,B\}\cup B=A=B$$
I'm pretty confident that the latter is correct since in $A$, $B$ is an element and not a subset but I just wanted to be sure

The answer in ZFC set theory is that this situation is impossible: you cannot have $A \in B$ and $B \in A$ at the same time because it gives an infinite membership chain $A \ni B \ni A \ni B \ni ...$, which is impossible by the axiom of foundation.

Jean's answer is perfectly right, but I would like to answer this a little differently.
I will show that the axioms of ZF force your sets to not exist in yet another way.
Let $A,B$ be two sets. Consider the axiom of pairing. This tells us that $C=\{A,B\}$ is a set. Now apply the axiom of regularity to $C$. There must be an element of $C$ that is disjoint from $C$. So it must be either $A$ or $B$. If it's $A$ then $B\notin A$, and if it's $B$ then $A\notin B$.
So $A\in B$ and $B\in A$ cannot ever occur simultaneously.
